# How do loan companies set interest rate tiers?

Tags: machine-learning, binning, partitioning, credit-scoring

What statistical or machine learning methods do companies like Lending Club use to segment their customer base into loan grades A1-G5? What would a reasonable partitioning method look like after running, say, a simple regression?

Comment: Did you try to Google 'credit risk modelling' because you can use a whole bunch of techniques, a.o. Logistic regression, neural networks, support vector machines, survival analysis, random forests, boosting, ...

Comment: @fcop There are tons of guides on getting relevant output but not how to properly segment that output. For example, how can probability of default be segmented into loan grades?

Comment: What about ordered logistic regression e.g ?  That gives you a score and the thresholds to use to partition the score range into rating classes ?